# Altium: Query to target Vias in Pads

Tags: pcb-design, altium, via

Does anyone have a Altium query/selector that targets vias in SMT pads? I'm routing a very dense HDI board, and would like to make rules that exclusively target vias that are inside a component pad and not normal vias or offset (dog-bone style) vias next to BGA pads.

(I'm aware of the tradeoffs involved in putting vias in pads, and the board house is going to fill and plate over them. I'm using Altium Designer release 27009 (Dec 2012)).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways:

### Method 1

This method assumes that the vias are created as part of the component, and not placed on the pcb directly.

1. Select all components [IsComponent] and move them away, dragging their attached vias (primitives) with them.
2. Select remaining regular vias with the mouse and somehow mark them, in this example by locking them.
3. Move back all components.
4. Filter using [IsVia and Not Locked]

### Method 2

Give the via some property that will make them easy to filter out.  For example, make all diameters of via in pads odd numbers that are very close to your desired drills, like 0.099mm instead of 0.1mm.  That way you can filter by drill diameter (or some other attribute).

Answer (score 0):

The only way that could be possible is the **Design Rule Check Wizard** in the Design bar, with **Advanced Rule Scope**.

If haven't solution by this, I think that is impossible do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the built in query stuff works for you, I think it should be possible to do this with a custom script somehow.

Assuming the via is placed at the exact center of the pad, it might be possible to build a "table" of pads and their center coordinates. Then build a table of vias and their coordinates. Find any that match and those are your vias in pads. How to apply a rule to this, I'm not sure - you might be able to script that as well.